# How to add, update, delete, and read on cloud firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to learn do add, insert, update, and delete on cloud firestore.
I already read cloud firestore documentation but i dont understand it since im really new to Could firestore and i just started learing android studio.

I already make the constructor and planning to use ListView to read the data and Delete and Update on the setOnLongClickListener with Intent to make editing easier. And i use another activity for the add function.

Most of the tutorial i meet are putting all in 1 place and make it harder to understand it.
And mixing code that i got from different resource making the code harder to understand and it look weird.

So what is the easy to understand code to do this with this database?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngnR7.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should require user authentication if you are going to be using the Firebase Android SDK to post data to your server and then your `firebase.rules` on your server should check that caller has right level of access.
2. Get an instance of `FirebaseFirestore` as in

   ```
   private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore
       get() = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
   ```
3. documents on Firebase always follow the pattern `document/collection/document/collection/...` example `val docName = "animalDoc/mammalCollection/rodentDoc/miceCollection/JerryDoc`
4. get all mice:

   ```
   firestore.collection("animalDoc/mammalCollection/"
   +"rodentDoc/miceCollection").get()
   .addOnSuccessListener { result -> //result is just a Kotlin collection
       val myFavoriteMouse = result.find { it["name"] == "Jerry" }
       // do something with Jer
   }
   ```
5. Set a mouse

   ```
   val docName = "animalDoc/mammalCollection/rodentDoc/miceCollection/JerryDoc"
                   firestore.document(docName).set(mapOfData).addOnCompleteListener {
                       if (it.isSuccessful) {
                           // log your success or whatever
                       } else {
                           // log your failure or whatever
                       }
                   }
   ```
6. Update a mouse

   ```
    val docName = "animalDoc/mammalCollection/rodentDoc/miceCollection/JerryDoc"
   val docRef = firestore.document(docName)
   firestore.runTransaction { transaction ->
       transaction.update(docRef, "color", "brown")
   }
   ```
7. Delete a mouse

   ```
   val docName = "animalDoc/mammalCollection/rodentDoc/miceCollection/JerryDoc"
   firestore.document(docName).delete()
   ```

Comment: thank you sir, but can you send me how the database look like?
i kind of doesnt understand how document/collection/document/collection/... look like